# White Toggle Button on NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation, toggle, drawer

I've developed a navigation drawer for my app, but the toggle button is shown in white. This is my image for the button

[image]

And this is how it is shown on my app

[image]

Does anyone know why this happends?

Answer (score 0):

You just make sure your app theme If you having your Theme like black you just apply this theme in your Application Mainfest file

```
  <application       
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
   ......
   ....

 </application>
```

Afterwards you are getting the same pblm you just make sure in your drawable folder image is like your gray color image or not...